# Custom 404 not found image

Tags: discussion, 404-page

Stack Overflow has an interesting 404 not found page:

> We couldn't find the page you requested. We did, however, find this program.
>   [image]

How about something like that for Code Golf?

Comment: Not until we graduate from beta.

Comment: >.> Just saying, There's a shorter one, `+++++++++++++[>++++<-]>.----.++++.`

Comment: I have a feeling that this actually a polyglot...

Comment: @Wally Yeah, that's the point. Ruby, Python, Perl, Befunge, C, BF. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28625/180276