# Let's get a special 404 page!

Tags: feature-request, site-design, 404-page

[Very related, but not the same](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/custom-404-not-found-image)

I would like it if someone could make this a community wiki.

---

In [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240), [mousetail](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/91213) posted [a message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64150630#64150630):

> Petition to make our 404 page a quine in "Lost"

This message has then received 10 stars, showing that the community would like this change, so I am asking on behalf of the community to make the 404 page a quine in the programming language "Lost".

`<there was another quine here>`

### Edit

Thanks to Wheat Wizard for pointing out a shorter quine by Jo King:

```
:2+52*95*2+>::1?:[:[[[[@^%?>([ "
////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: There's a shorter quine [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155002/56656).

Comment: A big problem here is that we don't actually have the ability to customise our 404 page. It used to be a thing, but [was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368048) as part of a design rework